# Restrict action to operated row AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't find a way to restrict the action triggered by ng-change to only the row operated by the user. So, if user selects "League" on dropdown 1, another dropdown should be displayed on the "Available Items" column. Right now if user operates row 1, all dropdowns from the table are affected by the action. What I need is to limit the action to only the row operated by user. Fiddle: https://plnkr.co/edit/kAiLw40hUvnLk9jv86aj?p=preview

```
<div class="col-md-12 limitObjects">
 <h4>Limit Object: </h4>
  <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 500px; height: 100%">
   <table border="0" class="table-bordered myTable" >
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in userMappings" ng-model="item">
      <td class="col-md-4">
        {{item.idsport}}, Game Type {{item.idgametype}}, {{item.name}} (Current limit {{item.value}}) {{item.mapped}}
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-3 mapType" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 15px" >
      <h4>Mapping Type: <span style="font-size:0.8em">{{mapping.name}}</span> </h4> 
      <select ng-model="mapping" ng-change="which(mapping, $index, event)" ng-options="mapping.name for mapping in mappingType" se-change=''></select>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-4" style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-left: 10px">
       <h4>Available Items:</h4>
       <select ng-show="buau" ng-model="sport" ng-change="getID(sport, $index, $event); table($event)"  ng-options="sport.name for sport in sportsList"></select>
       <select ng-show="buau == false" ng-model="sportLeague" ng-change="getLeaguecategories(sportLeague, $index, $event)" ng-options="sportLeague.name for sportLeague in sportsList" style="float: left;"></select>
       <select ng-show="!buau"  ng-model="selectedLeague" ng-change="getID(selectedLeague, $index)" ng-options="selectedLeague.name for selectedLeague in leagueList.response" ></select>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

<script>
$scope.mappingType = [{name: "Sport"}, {name: "League"}, {name: "No Mapping"}];

$scope.sportsList = [{id : 34, name : "[Default]"}, {id: 15, name : "Alpine Skiing"}, { id : 8,  name : "American Football" }, { id : 23,  name : "Australian Rules"}];

$scope.userMappings = [{"id":"1","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"Side","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"3000"},{"id":"2","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"4","name":"Total","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"3000"},{"id":"3","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"IfBets","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"500"},{"id":"4","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"MoneyLine","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"2000"},{"id":"5","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"1","name":"Parlays","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"700"},{"id":"6","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"Related","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"0"},{"id":"7","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"0","name":"Reverses","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"500"},{"id":"8","idgametype":"81","idsport":"NFL","mapped":"2","name":"Teasers","online":"1","profilelimitkeyid":"1","value":"0"}];

$scope.buau = true;

$scope.which = function(mapping, index) {
 if ( mapping.name === "Sport" ){
    $scope.buau = true;       
 } else if ( mapping.name === "League" ) {
    $scope.buau = false;
 } else if (mapping.name === "No Mapping" ){

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the you're using the same variable in your `ng-show` condition for all the rows, so it's natural that all the rows would always change together. You can fix this by adding a property to each item in the ng-repeat like this

```
<select ng-model="item.mapping" ng-change="which(item, $index, event)" ng-options="mapping.name for mapping in mappingType" se-change=''></select>

<select ng-show="item.buau" ng-model="sport" ng-change="getID(sport, $index, $event); table($event)"  ng-options="sport.name for sport in sportsList"></select>

<select ng-show="item.buau == false" ng-model="sportLeague" ng-change="getLeaguecategories(sportLeague, $index, $event)" ng-options="sportLeague.name for sportLeague in sportsList" style="float: left;"></select>

 <select ng-show="!item.buau"  ng-model="selectedLeague" ng-change="getID(selectedLeague, $index)" ng-options="selectedLeague.name for selectedLeague in leagueList.response" ></select>
```

so you're attaching the mapping/buau properties to each item that way it's unique, and in you're controller:

```
$scope.which = function(item, index) {



  if ( item.mapping.name === "Sport" ){

      item.buau = true;


  } else if ( item.mapping.name === "League" ) {
           item.buau = false;

  } else if (item.mapping.name === "No Mapping" ){


  }



}
```

here's a working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rENbv8h3Pp7tm82YLpQS?p=preview

Comment: Thanx Ahmed, it works as expected. Now I'm trying to restrict a function to the operated row. I updated the Fiddle at : https://embed.plnkr.co/kAiLw40hUvnLk9jv86aj/

If you select "league" on dropdown 1, you then select a sport on the upper dropdown 2 to then have another dropdown with displayed leagues. I can't find a way to restrict the triggered function to only the row operated by user. Right now triggered function populates all dropdowns. Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: @EnriquedelBosque I don't quite understand what the problem is. Which function are you having trouble with exactly? What exactly is the end result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, action triggered by ngChange="getLeaguecategories()"  should only affect the row operated by user. If user selects "League" on dropdown1, 2 dropdowns should be displayed on the "AvailableItems" column. Top dropdown lets you select a sport, when selected, down dropdown displays league options. Problem is that all league options dropdowns from the table get populated after triggering function for the 1st time (if you select "league" on another row's dropdown, league options are already displayed before you select your sport). Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/kAiLw40hUvnLk9jv86aj?p=preview

Comment: Well you could do to the `$scope.leagueList` variable same thing i did in my answer above, which is attach it to each item by passing the `item` object to the `getLeaguecategories` function and attach the list of leagues to `item.leagueList`. Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tOJ7tFLsbAzMGklfwFlf?p=preview . Just want to point out that while this will work there might be a more efficient way of doing this but hard to advise you about it without knowing the full scope of your app and all the details.